# Show that $f(x)= \frac{x^{-1/2}}{1+ | \log x |} $ is only $L_{p} ((0,\infty])$ for p=2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Show that
$
{\rm f}\left(x\right)= {x^{-1/2}
 \over
 1 + \left\vert\,\log\left(x\right)\,\right\vert}$ is only
$L_{p}\left(\vphantom{\large A}\left(0,\infty\right]\right)$ for $p = 2$.
Where $x > 0$.

For the case $p = 2$, I think that I need to show that the function is bounded when raised to the pth power near 0. For the other cases I expect the function to be unbounded. When I look at graphs of the functions however, they all look pretty similar to me. I guess there are separate arguments for when $p = 1$ and $p > 2$.
Any hints or  help would be great.

Hmm, I think that my talk about boundedness being necessary for the Lebesgue integral to exist is off. So if there's another thought I should explore that would be great.Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $L_p([0,\infty))$? Usually lowercase notation is used for sequences. Hints: Deal with the two cases $x$ near 0 and $x$ far from zero. Try the bound $x^{-1/2}/(1+|\log x|) \leq x^{-1/2}/|\log x|$ for one of these regions.

Comment: ahh. I didn't realize that, yes. My mistake , I am going to edit it. Thanks

Comment: hi nayrb, I am trying to see what to do with the hint. Am I interested in showing that $\frac{ x^{-1/2}}{(1+|\log x| )}$ is $L_{p}$ integrable; and thus that the smaller functions are as well for x very large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget boundedness and think of *comparison*. What can you compare $|f|^p$ to?

The logarithm grows slower than any positive power of $x$ at infinity, and slower than any negative power of $x$ at $0$. Think of it as $x$ raised to infinitesimally small power, if it helps.

- for every $\epsilon$ you have   $|f(x)|^p   \ge x^{-p/2-\epsilon}$  when $x$ is large enough.  When $p<2$, this makes $|f|^p$ nonintegrable on $(0,\infty)$. (Nothing special is needed for $p=1$.)
- for every $\epsilon$ you have   $|f(x)|^p   \ge x^{-p/2+\epsilon}$  when $x$ is small enough.  When $p>2$, this makes $|f|^p$ nonintegrable on $(0,\infty)$.

To show $f^2$ is integrable, do a direct computation involving the substitution $u=\log x$.